# Turn Linux into Router (Cisco-like)

Tags: linux, cisco, router, command-line-interface

how you doing?

I have two Sophos UTM 220 Appliance for study. They have 8 Gigabit Ethernet ports and the hardware is like a common PC (Intel Motherboard, Processor and DDR2 Memory).

I would like to turn these appliances into a router closer to a Cisco one, with based CLI and most capabilities possible (Dynamic Routing, ACL, VLAN, Networking Management etc).

Is there some Linux distro for doing this? 
- I know well pfSense, but is hasn't a CLI. 
- I has wondering about Vyatta, but now it's a commercial product under Brocade domain. 
- I also saw VyOS, a Vyatta fork, but there's no strong community/docs.

Or what do you think of installing a clean Linux distro (CentOS, btw), and start studying and deploying from scratch? What package should I use? I read about Quagga and RPC100, and found it really interesting.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use [Quagga](http://www.nongnu.org/quagga/).

Comment: Can I achieve everything I said before just with Quagga? Do you know some docs about advanced routing in Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Basically any distro can do if you just have 2-3 interfaces, a DHCP and a routing function.

One interface will get WAN feed from the internet.
Second interface will be connected to like a switch for LAN with DHCP enabled on this side.
Third interface is an optional DMZ.

And the Linux would have a static route to forward all second interface traffic to first WAN interface.

I recommend PFsense and it's easy to deploy. You can install and configure using GUI on a web browser.
For complicated VLAN and ACL management, you would want a PFsense.
Another alternative is SmoothWall.

That's basically what all managed routers are doing. They are like small computers routing and NATing.

Comment: This kind of router I know how to deploy, especially with pfSense (got some clients with it) and its really great. But what I real want is something closer to the CLI of Cisco.

Comment: "That's basically what all managed routers are doing. They are like small computers routing and NATing." <--- except that they have very specialized hardware that lets them push orders of magnitude more packets that you could ever get from a server-router.